# How can i get id/pk from a url

Tags: django, django-views

I am a Django newbie trying to create a flight booking view that will take logged in user id and the pk/id of the selected flight so i can combine the data and populate a ticket for the corresponding user and the selected flight. I don’t have any idea how to make this work, i have tried searching for answers and no luck. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

**forms.py**

```
 class BookFlightForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta: 
            model = Booking
            fields = ("flight", "board_class")
```

**views.py**

```
 class BookFlightView(generic.FormView):
        model = Booking
        template_name = "book_flight.html"
        form_class = BookFlightForm
    
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse("flightbook:booked")
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            data = form.cleaned_data
            flight = data['flight'] #here i am getting the flight manually
            board_class = data['board_class']
            Booking.objects.create(
                passenger = self.request.user.client,
                flight = flight,
                board_class = board_class
            )
            return super(BookFlightView, self).form_valid(form)
    
    class BookedView(generic.TemplateView):
        template_name = "booked.html"
```

**urls.py**

```
 urlpatterns = [
        path('', FlightListView.as_view(), name="flight-list"),
        path('<int:pk>/flight-details/', FlightDetailView.as_view(), name="flight-details"),
        path('<int:pk>/book-flight/', BookFlightView.as_view(), name="book-flight"),
        path('booked/', BookedView.as_view(), name="booked"),
        
    ]
```

**models.py**

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    AIRLINE = [
        ('ATCL', 'ATCL'),
        ('Fast Jet', 'Fast Jet'),
        ('Fly Emirates', 'Fly Emirates'),
        ('Kenyan Airways', 'Kenyan Airways'),
        ('Ethiopian Airways', 'Ethiopian Airways'),
        ('Malaysian Airways', 'Malaysian Airways'),

    ]
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    airline = models.CharField(choices= AIRLINE, max_length=20)
    depart_city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dapart_country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    depart_airport = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    destination_city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    destination_country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    destination_airport = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Booking(models.Model):
    CLASS = [
        ('Business','Business'),
        ('Business','Business'),
        ('Royal','Royal'),
    ]
    passenger = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flight = models.ForeignKey(Flight, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    board_class = models.CharField(choices= CLASS, null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
```

Comment: The best place to start would be Django's documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Work through a book on full stack developing with python/django and sql databases. This will take time and energy. There's no shortcut around learning.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello, bro please share your code where how do you want, so that we can solve your problem.

Comment: Hello Bro @shahsawood , i have not really write any code on the view i am still looking for some insight on how i can archive the functionality. Thank You

Answer (score -1):

## in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def test(request, Id, name):
    return render(
        request,
        "app2/test.html",
        {
            "id": Id,
            "name": name,
        },
    )
```

## in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("test/<int:Id>/<str:name>", views.test, name="test"),
]
```

## test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Id: {{ Id }}</div>
    <div>Name: {{ name|title }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now visit 127.0.0.1:8000/.../test/1/ShahSawood
will show in the html page `test.html`

Comment: I have added some code of what i am trying to do, have a look at it